# How to install pub (command line usage) for Dart on Ubuntu web-server

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, dart, server, dart-pub

I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download-editor.html?utm_expid=51752263-1.WpTWnsvDTEGD1RYXp5u58g.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F) (under the Linux tab) on installing Dart onto a Ubuntu web-server.

Dart itself works fine, but I can't use Pub commands (only Dart commands). How can I install Pub for the server?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here are Dart’s installation instructions for 64bit version of Ubuntu using the Aptitude (apt) package manager (as found on the website):

```
# Enable HTTPS for apt. 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https 

# Get the Google Linux package signing key. 
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -' 

# Set up the location of the stable repository.
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list' 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install dart
```

After this though, it’s likely that the Pub commands will not work in the terminal even if the Dart language does (yours might be different, try entering ‘pub –-help’ to see). If this is the case, Pub can be enabled manually by adding Dart to the ‘.profile’ PATH.

It’s likely that the newly installed Dart files will be located in the ‘/usr/lib/dart’ directory (do check this if unsure). Once known, edit the ‘.profile’ file by entering:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

This will edit the bash profile using nano (if installed, else use another command line file editor). Now at the bottom of the file, add:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"
```

When finished, you can check it has saved afterwards by entering ‘cat ~/.profile’. Now force the bash profile to reload by entering:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Enter ‘pub –help’ again to check and hopefully the Pub help information is shown. Thank you Günter Zöchbauer for the hint ;)

Comment: Is not there a way to do last 3 lines without opening the file, so I can write .sh file to execute the full set of command? thanks.

Comment: @HasanAYousef You mean `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"' > $HOME/.profile`?

Answer (score 13):

I guess you just need to add the `dart-sdk/bin` directory to the path or alternatively create symlinks in `/usr/bin` for the Dart tools you want to have easily available.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not even sure where that is in Ubuntu? I found the .deb file, but where does it go once it's installed?

Comment: `locate pub` or `locate pub. sh`

Comment: In your second suggestion, did you mean locate pub.sh?

Comment: Yup, the space was not intentional.

Answer (score 13):

Another work-around is creating a link to `pub`

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub /usr/bin/pub`

https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link

Answer (score 1):

Günter Zöchbauer already told you how to get the program (it's apparently already installed by default with `dart`, but just isn't in the path for some reason). To find the path to `pub`, you can install `dart` with your `.deb` installation file, and open the `synaptic package manager` (type sudo synaptic from the command-line; install synaptic first, if it's not installed—`sudo apt-get install synaptic`), find dart in the Synaptic Package Manager. Right click on `dart`. Click on `properties`. Go to the `installed files` tab. Look for `pub` to see where it's installed. Here's where mine is: `/usr/lib/dart/bin/pub`. The 'included files' tab while using `gdebi` to open the `.deb` file may be insightful as to where it will put it, too.

Then type this from the command-line (substituting your path to `pub` if it's not like mine); this will add `pub` to your path:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pub pub /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub 0
```

You may need to check first to see if `pub` is assigned to something else already (it sounds like you already know that it's not, but it's good to know how to do this for the future, including if you want to change which one is assigned at a particular time):

```
update-alternatives --config pub
```

That will let you see what typing `pub` will run, what alternatives are currently configured for that, and allow you to change which program (of the alternatives) will run when you type `pub`. If it is assigned to something else, the `0` at the end of the first command I mentioned might need to be changed to a different number.

Note: There are other programs besides pub in the same directory that you might want to add to your path.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's as described by @willsquire, but for the lastest installation instructions head to https://dart.dev/get-dart