# How to start Dart project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, dart, flutter

During installation of Flutter plugin it was said that Dart plugin will also be installed. So I installed them both. But when I open "File > New" menu I see "New Flutter project", "New Project" but nothing about Dart.
In "New Project" dialog I see "Include C++ support", "Include Kotlin support" only.
How could I start simple Dart project ?

Comment: Android Studio has been specifically created for Android development. If you want to create Dart projects - and you already know the Android Studio user interface - using IntelliJ IDEA's free Community Edition is your best option. Check the IntelliJ Dart plugin page for more details: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/jetbrains-plugin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider installing IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, which should feel familiar if you use Android Studio. Install the Dart language plugin and you'll get the File / New Project options for Dart programs. (This just provides a wizard front-end to stagehand, as described by creative creator.) Note that you must download and install the Dart SDK also. (Do not try to use the Dart SDK provided by Flutter for plain Dart projects.)

Comment: you said don't use dart SDK provided by flutter for plain dart project, could you let me the reason?

Comment: It's modified for flutter (html removed, etc). It's no hardship to download the regular Dart SDK separately.

Comment: As of Flutter 1.21, the Flutter SDK includes the full Dart SDK. (Source: https://dart.dev/get-dart)

Answer (score 3):

This option does **not** exist.

What you want to use is ***[`stagehand`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehand)***.

It is a *pub* plugin that is installed by using `pub` in your command line. You probably want to [add it to your path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28469770/6509751).

When that is done, `stagehand` is installed like this:

```
pub global activate stagehand
```

When you navigated to a directory you will be able to create a *Dart project* from [a template](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehandstagehand-templates):

```
stagehand console-full
```

The command will create a *Dart project* ready for simple console applications in the *current directory*.

Comment: `stagehand` is discontinued in favor of `dart create` now.

Answer (score 0):

Dart itself is a language which is meant to be used for web development, Flutter uses Dart to make apps for Android and iOS, and Android Studio is a mobile development IDE, if you want to use Dart for the web, you should use IntelliJ IDEA (Android Studio is based on it, they are very similar) and [the Dart plugin](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/jetbrains-plugin).