# How to run a Dart program without running simulator/emulator in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to run this code in Android studio without firing up any device, I just want to print it to the console.

```
void main() {
  print("Hello World");
}
```

**Note:**

I am not looking for `DartPad` or any other online IDE to run Dart code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977917/how-to-start-dart-project-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Unix-like system (e.g. Linux, macOS), if `dart` is in your executable `PATH`, you can add a shebang line to your `.dart` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env dart

void main() {
  print("Hello World");
}
```

and mark your file executable (`chmod a+x your_file.dart`).  Then you can run `your_file.dart` directly without needing to run `dart your_file.dart` explicitly.

(If the `dart` binary is not in `PATH`, then you would need to use `#!/full/path/to/dart` as the first line instead.)

On Windows, you could set up a file association for `.dart` files.

Comment: Thanks but I am very new to these commands, can you tell me how do I check if my `dart` is in `PATH`?

Comment: Open a terminal window and try running `dart` by itself.

Answer (score 2):

in your Dart file right click on the **green arrows** in front of your `main()` function:

[image]

then click on the ***dart icon*** from the popup menu`Create ...`

[image]

and then `OK`:

[image]

now you can run it without the simulator:

[image]

And get the console output in the **Run** window:

[image]